# An indentity column keep auto-incrementing by 1000 instead of 1 in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T] (
    [TId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    [ModifiedDate] DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

I understand the idea of the identity column is to increment by one but I notice that for **this** particular table it always seems like it increments by 1000. Can someone tell me why this is? I have other tables and as far as I can see those others just increment by 1.

Comment: Increment by 1000 you mean 
`1` `1001` `2001` `3001` and so.

Comment: I mean I add three rows and the values are 1001,1002 and 1003. Then later add another three and the values are 2001,2002 and 2003 :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a SQL Server bug reported earlier

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity

Description

When a table with less than 1000 rows that has an identity value is part of a database that is failed over in an AlwaysOn availability group, the identity is reseeded to 1000. If the identity value is already over 1000, no reseed occurs.

This also occurs if you restart the server.

Comment: Well that's odd as most of my tables have less than 1,000 and they don't increase by 1,000 each time. Also the table in question is now at identity value 8,000+ The only thing I can think of is some of those other tables have around 200 rows and were populated all at once.

Comment: No I've not tried a workaround. I am using Azure SQL Server so I'm quite limited as to what I can change. I will leave as is for now. Thanks for your advice.